# Alternative to valgrind without 32Gb mem limit?

Tags: c, debugging

I am a great fan of valgrind, and have used it extensively to catch bugs in my code. However right now I am stuck with a bug which only manifests in particular circumstances, which require my program to malloc/use more than 32Gb of RAM (about 37 in fact), and valgrind has a hard-coded limit which says it won't let you alloc more than 32Gb. I've managed to find a couple of postings online where people list various code modifications to valgrind which should allow you to extend this limit, but either they do not seem to work, or they seem to be modifying a different (and unspecified) version of valgrind. I'm not to keen on hacking around inside valgrind anyway, so I've started looking for other options.

Clang/AddressSanitizer seemed a good option, but there is a hitch there also unfortunately, as I make a lot of use of nested functions. So, my question is - does anyone know of an alternative to valgrind which (on 64bit linux) does not have the 32Gb memory allocation limit that valgrind does?

Ideas v welcome
best
Zam

Comment: You mentioned AddressSanitizer, but have you tried the clang static analyzer?  As a static analyzer it doesn't replace a memory error detector like valgrind or AddressSanitizer but I recently started using it and did correct some memory related bugs that way.

Comment: Another place to look:
https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/ComparisonOfMemoryTools
Here five competing memory checkers are listed, of which Valgrind and AddressSanitizer are just two.

Comment: Thanks Doug! I have not tried clang at all because it specifies that it does not support nested functions. I'll take a look at that wiki though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A gcc variant of AddressSanitizer is now available in the gcc trunk (soon to be 4.8).
It's not as mature as the clang version yet, but you may try.

```
% cat use-after-free.cc 
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  char *x = (char*)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
  free(x);
  return x[5];
}
% g++ --version | head -1 
g++ (GCC) 4.8.0 20130216 (experimental)

% g++ -fsanitize=address -static-libasan  use-after-free.cc && ./a.out 2>&1 | asan_symbolize.py 
=================================================================
==9817== ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x60040000dff5 at pc 0x4179c3 bp 0x7fffe046af30 sp 0x7fffe046af28
READ of size 1 at 0x60040000dff5 thread T0
    #0 0x4179c2 in main ??:0
    #1 0x7f469c8dc76c in __libc_start_main /build/buildd/eglibc-2.15/csu/libc-start.c:226
    #2 0x402098 in _start ??:0
0x60040000dff5 is located 5 bytes inside of 10-byte region [0x60040000dff0,0x60040000dffa)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x40f18a in free ??:0
    #1 0x417980 in main ??:0
    #2 0x7f469c8dc76c in __libc_start_main /build/buildd/eglibc-2.15/csu/libc-start.c:226
previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x40f26a in malloc ??:0
    #1 0x417970 in main ??:0
    #2 0x7f469c8dc76c in __libc_start_main /build/buildd/eglibc-2.15/csu/libc-start.c:226
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also an Open Source memory debugger for Linux and Windows. It is called ["Dr. Memory"](http://www.drmemory.org). I don't know if it has an upper limit (like valgrind), but maybe you should try.